# How do I invert a raster mask in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I have a raster binary mask created from DEM. From that I want to mask another image. I want the values 0 to be one or in simple words invert the mask. How to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
// Filtering Sentinel-2 Imagery
var mask = (srtm.gt(150).and(srtm.lt(200))).clip(geometry).selfMask();
Map.addLayer(mask, {}, 'Raster Mask')

var S2_L2A = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED");
var from_date = '2022-06-26';
var to_date = '2022-06-30';
var filtered_collection = S2_L2A.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate(from_date, to_date)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10));
print(filtered_collection.size(), 'Number of Images In the Filtered Collection');
print(filtered_collection);
var image = filtered_collection.mosaic();
Map.addLayer(image, {min:93, max:4060, bands:['B4','B3','B2']}, 'Sentinel Image');

var sentinel_imageC = image.updateMask(mask);
Map.addLayer(sentinel_imageC, imageVisParam, 'Sentinel Image to Clip')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb90ba023f091f647dfbee2bc0e0ef06

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the mask can be achieved in multiple ways. But most importantly is that you define the mask correctly, applying .selfMask() in your case doesn't result in your anticipated result. In stead try:

```
var mask = srtm.gt(150).and(srtm.lt(200)).clip(geometry) // Your attempt
var invertMask = srtm.lt(150).or(srtm.gt(200)).clip(geometry) // option 1
var invertMask2 = mask.eq(0)                             // option 2
```

remaining difference between option 1 and 2 are inclusive boundaries or not.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d92f8e3a2ac920a3211129fa7183f4f3

Comment: Use [not](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-not).